# Hyperlegder Fabric: CA certificate does not have CA attribute even though it does

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, x509certificate

I'm trying to set up a Hyperledger Fabric install with my own Certificate Authority and user. I'm using **version 1.4.6**. I'm getting closer. But this is what happens when I try to create a channel:

```
peer channel create -o orderer.diro.umontreal.ca:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/indepedent/orderer/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
```

In response, I get:

```
Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/indepedent/admin3/msp: CA Certificate did not have the CA attribute, (SN: 6143ea1883f7a36a3d794bfab314ea05d9ddd270)
```

`admin3` is my current attempt at registering an admin with the CA. However, here's what happens when I try to look inside the CA certificate for that user:

```
openssl x509 -in crypto-config/indepedent/admin3/msp/cacerts/localhost-7054.pem -text -noout | grep CA:
            CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
```

So it seems to have the CA attribute after all. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the certificate present at: `crypto-config/indepedent/admin3/msp/tlscacerts` folder and verify if it is a CA certificate or not.

Comment: That one, the one at `tlscacerts` is not a CA certificate. Without it, there is no `https` connection at all, and with it there is one. I don't know how to generate a certificate that both satisfy the TLS and CA requirements. Any type of user generation I have tried fails to do that. Creating a CA server with TLS creates two root certificates, one called `ca-cert.pem` that has CA but not TLS and one called `tls-cert.pem` that has TLS but no CA. The one in `cacerts` is just a copy of `ca-certs.pem`.

Comment: For `tlscacerts`, I added myself and I just put a copy of `tls-cert.pem` in it. And it worked, partially. It allowed for TLS connections.

Comment: I'm not near my Linux computer now, but I think I tried putting `ca-cert.pem` in `tlscacerts` and that didn't work: a TLS connection could not be established, but I'll try again.

Comment: Based on more extensive researche, what  `tls-cert.pem` has that `ca-cert.pem` does not have is the line `DNS:localhost` of type `Subject Alternative Name`. What `ca-cert.pem` has is the essential `CA:TRUE`. I cannot seem to create a key by hand that is not an RSA key.

Comment: Let's say if you are using your own Certificate Authority then create an ECDSA key (let's say all your identities follow 256-bit keys). Followed by that create **self-signed** certificate (public key) which has the same subject line as CA certificate and add SAN value corresponding to `localhost`. You can easily use `openssl` for non-production environments at least.

Comment: I tried using openssl, but I couldn't figure out the right command. Now that I know it's what I need to do, I will try again.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get everything working, but I got that part working and it was not obvious, so I'm documenting it here in case it helps someone in the future:

First, make the key. Not the certificate, just the key:

```
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -param_enc named_curve -out private-key.pem
```

The `prime` type of eliptic curves seems to be the ones that work, and it's important that they are `named_cure` types. You can change the size. That part is in the documentation.

Then make the certificate:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key private-key.pem -out tls-cert.pem -subj '/CN=Same name as original'  -days 10000 -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:localhost"
```

Now, when I started the CA, it didn't work. It wanted a private key. It gave a long hex number for the private key. I copied the private key into the keystore as a file named `<long_number>_sk` but that was not enough. That file contains two sections and the first one must be removed. So I had to go in and remove the first three lines.

That worked. After doing that, I had my CA certificate that also worked as a TLS certificate. But now, I have to recreate all of my users.

I tried adding a config file with the `-config` option, but that removed the essential `CA:TRUE` attribute.

[EDIT]

I also managed to make a config file that works and makes the same thing with a shorter command:

```
[ req ]
distinguished_name     = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions        = v3_intermediate_ca

[ v3_intermediate_ca ]
subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer
basicConstraints       = critical, CA:true, pathlen:0
keyUsage               = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign
subjectAltName         = @alt_names

[ req_distinguished_name ]
C                      = US
ST                     = CA
L                      = City
O                      = Institution
OU                     = Department
CN                     = main-ca

[ alt_names ]
DNS.0                  = CN localhost
```

And then:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -key private-key.pem -out tls-cert.pem -subj '/CN=The Subject' -days 10000 -config openssl.cnf
```

Comment: With the config file if you are not getting the `CA:TRUE` value then that could be set in the config file itself. Check the default `openssl_root.cnf` file used by `openssl`. Also I don't think so that you need to store private key in `<long_number>_sk` format. Directly you store the `private-key.pem` generated by first command in PEM format itself in the required `keystore` directory.

Comment: You know what? Maybe it would have worked if I had edited the file after copying it. I tried renaming it before I tried editing it.